# Group by result of top hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

```
{
    "took": 53,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiyjHmzUObmc5euUGS",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "james",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 02:03:11",
                "browser": "chrome",
                "offercode": "JB20"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiyjIQzUObmc5euUGT",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "james",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 03:04:15",
                "browser": "firefox",
                "offercode": "JB20,JB50"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiyjIlzUObmc5euUGU",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "james",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/21 00:15:21",
                "browser": "chrome",
                "offercode": "JB20,JB50,JB100"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiyjJKzUObmc5euUGW",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "peter",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 02:32:22",
                "browser": "chrome",
                "offercode": "JB20,JB50,JB100"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiy4jhzUObmc5euUGX",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "james",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/19 02:03:11",
                "browser": "chrome",
                "offercode": ""
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "db",
            "_type": "users",
            "_id": "AVOiyjI2zUObmc5euUGV",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "user": "adams",
                "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 00:12:11",
                "browser": "chrome",
                "offercode": "JB10"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to filter out the document based on the user last visited time and get the most recent accessed document of an individual user and then group all the filtered documents based on offer code.

I get the most recent accessed document of an user by performing tophits aggregation. But, I can't able to group the results of tophits aggregation using the offercode.

**ES Query to get most recent document of a user**

```
    curl -XGET localhost:9200/account/users/_search?pretty -d'{
 "size": "0",
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "lastvisited": {
            "gte": "2016/01/19",
             "lte": "2016/01/21" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
 },
"aggs": {
  "lastvisited_users": {
      "terms": {
          "field": "user"
     }
    ,
    "aggs": {
       "top_user_hits": {
           "top_hits": {
              "sort": [
               {
                 "lastvisited": {
                   "order": "desc"
                 }
               }
             ],
             "_source": {
                 "include": [
                     "user","offercode","lastvisited"
                  ]
              },
              "size": 1
            }
        }   
    }
  }
}}'
```

**ES Output**

```
   {
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "lastvisited_users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "james",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "top_user_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 3,
            "max_score" : null,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "accounts",
              "_type" : "users",
              "_id" : "AVOtexIEz1WBU8vnnZ2d",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "lastvisited" : "2016/01/20 03:04:15",
                "offercode" : "JB20,JB50",
                "user" : "james"
              },
              "sort" : [ 1453259055000 ]
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "adams",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "top_user_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 1,
            "max_score" : null,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "accounts",
              "_type" : "users",
              "_id" : "AVOtexJMz1WBU8vnnZ2h",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "lastvisited" : "2016/01/20 00:12:11",
                "offercode" : "JB10",
                "user" : "adams"
              },
              "sort" : [ 1453248731000 ]
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "adamsnew",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "top_user_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 1,
            "max_score" : null,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "accounts",
              "_type" : "users",
              "_id" : "AVOtexJhz1WBU8vnnZ2i",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "lastvisited" : "2016/01/20 00:12:11",
                "offercode" : "JB1010,aka10",
                "user" : "adamsnew"
              },
              "sort" : [ 1453248731000 ]
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "peter",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "top_user_hits" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 1,
            "max_score" : null,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "accounts",
              "_type" : "users",
              "_id" : "AVOtexIoz1WBU8vnnZ2f",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "lastvisited" : "2016/01/20 02:32:22",
                "offercode" : "JB20,JB50,JB100",
                "user" : "peter"
              },
              "sort" : [ 1453257142000 ]
            } ]
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to aggregate the results of tophits aggregation.

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "offercode_grouped": {
      "JB20": 1,
      "JB10": 1,
      "JB20,JB50": 1,
      "JB20,JB50,JB100": 2,
      "":1
   }
}
```

I tried using Pipeline aggregation but I don't know how to groupby the result of tophits aggregation.

Comment: please share the mapping of your index.

Comment: @Richa added es mapping in the post

Comment: You won't be able to `groupby` on the basis `offercode` as it an `analyzed` string and the value 'JB20,JB50,JB100` will get split into `JB20` ,`JB50`,`JB100` .

Comment: @Richa no problem I will change the field to not_analyzed. But I want to know is that possible to get the result if I change the analysis.

Comment: You can get  the most recent visited document of an user by applying  `aggregation` on `user` field but then you won't be able to aggregate on `offer` field. I will try and get back to you .

Answer (score 3):

I hope that I understand your problem correctly. I think I found a bit hacky "solution".

It is a combination of [`function_score query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), [`sampler aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) and [`terms aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

#### Create new index

```
curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string", 
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "lastvisited": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "browser": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "offercode": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

#### Index documents

```
curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/1?routing=james" -d'
{
  "user": "james",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 02:03:11",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "offercode": "JB20"
}'

curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/2?routing=james" -d'
{
  "user": "james",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 03:04:15",
  "browser": "firefox",
  "offercode": "JB20,JB50"
}'

curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/3?routing=james" -d'
{
  "user": "james",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/21 00:15:21",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "offercode": "JB20,JB50,JB100"
}'

curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/4?routing=peter" -d'
{
  "user": "peter",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 02:32:22",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "offercode": "JB20,JB50,JB100"
}'

curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/5?routing=james" -d'
{
  "user": "james",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/19 02:03:11",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "offercode": ""
}'

curl -s -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/document/6?routing=adams" -d'
{
  "user": "adams",
  "lastvisited": "2016/01/20 00:12:11",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "offercode": "JB10"
}'
```

#### Get aggregations

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/stackoverflow/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace", // we need to replace document score with the result of the functions
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": { // get documents within the date range
                "lastvisited": {
                  "gte": "2016/01/19 00:00:00",
                  "lte": "2016/01/21 23:59:59"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "linear": {
            "lastvisited": {
              "origin": "2016/01/21 23:59:59", // same as lastvisited lte filter
              "scale": "2d" // set the scale - please, see elasticsearch docs for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user": {
      "sampler": { // get top scored document per user
        "field": "user",
        "max_docs_per_value": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "offers": { // aggregate user documents per `offercode`
          "terms": {
            "field": "offercode"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

#### Response

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "user": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "offers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "JB20,JB50,JB100",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "JB10",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Unless you have only one shard per index, you need to specify [`routing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/mapping-routing-field.html) when indexing data**. It is because `sampler` aggregation is calculated **per shard**. So we need to ensure that all data of particular user will be in the same shard - to get one document with highest score per user.

`Sampler` aggregation returns documents by score. That is why we need to modify score of the documents. There is where `function_score query` can help. Using `field_value_factor`, the score is just the timestamp of last visit - so the more recent the visit, the higher the score.

**UPDATE:** With `field_value_factor` there is probably problem with `_score` accuracy. For more info see issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11872. That is why `decay` function is used as clintongormley suggested in the issue. Because [decay function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) works for both sides from `origin`. It means that documents 1 day older and 1 day younger than `origin` recevive the same `_score`. That's why we need to filter out newer documents (see range filter in the query).

NOTE: I tried this query just with the data which you can see in the example, so bigger dataset is needed to test the query. But I think it should work...

Comment: Absolutely, this is what I expected. It worked fine with smaller data, I tried with 10000 records. The aggregation only returns the output for 13 documents.

https://jsfiddle.net/bk94eLqu/

Comment: And how many users are in the documents? If 13 users, than it works as intended (there is still chance I don't fully understand your use case :) ). It should get one document per user (the fresh one - with last lastvisited) and calculate aggregations for these 13 documents...

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  I have 10000 unique users in the index type.  But,  aggregation returns just 13

Comment: I tried to generate dataset with 10000 unique users. When 1 shard was used, aggregation returns 100 documents. It is because `shard_size` option for sampler aggregation defaults to 100. Increasing the value helped. I tried it with 100 shards too (using `routing` as mentioned in answer). It was a lot slower. Especially with high `shard_size` option. So I don't think it is suitable for production, but should work...(https://gist.github.com/vhyza/4999ff9225251ee0a450)

Comment: I am facing a problem with function score query. It returns the same score for all matching documents. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: This is probably similar problem to: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11872. I update the query in the answer to `decay` function as clintongormley suggested...

Comment: Thank you :), I am looking forward for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution: it's more limited, but it is suitable for production: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788948/4769188

Answer (score -3):

This may solve your problem:

```
SELECT offercode, count(offercode) 
FROM users AS u1 
WHERE u1.ID = (SELECT u2.ID FROM users AS u2 WHERE u2.user = u1.user ORDER BY u2.lastvisited DESC LIMIT 1) 
AND u1.lastvisited >= "2016/01/20" 
AND ORDER BY lastvisited ASC AND GROUP BY offercode;
```

Comment: I expect he's asking for an elastic DSL query. You should explain your answer if you are trying to suggest an approach, using SQL.