# Get the latest document version and aggregate the results

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

My index contains a lot of documents, each of them has several versions, for example:

```
{"doc_id": 13,
"version": 1,
"text": "bar"}

{"doc_id": 13,
"version": 2,
"text": "bar"}

{"doc_id": 13,
"version": 3,
"text": "bar"}

{"doc_id": 14,
"version": 1,
"text": "foo"}

{"doc_id": 14,
"version": 2,
"text": "bar"}
```

I want to get the last version for each document, and aggregate them (last versions) using `terms` aggregation.
I've tried to use `top hits` to retrieve last versions:

```
{"size" :0,
"aggs" : {
    "doc_id_groups" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "doc_id",
            "size" : "0"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "docs" : {
                "top_hits" : {
                    "size" : 1,
                    "sort" : {
                        "version" : {
                            "order" : "desc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But I can't do aggregation, because `top hits` doesn't support sub aggregations.
I guess retrieving ids and then aggregating them would be very heavy operation for the client.
Maybe scripting could help?

**Update:** one thing I forgot to mention: before aggregating the documents are filtered by time range, so we don't know which version is the latest at index time, only at search time

Comment: Given the above example docs, what result are you expecting?

Comment: @jay I've edided example a little bit. I'm expecting something like this: `"buckets": [
            {
               "key": "bar",
               "doc_count": 2
            }]`

Comment: Do you need this to be done in one go or would it be ok to create a secondary index to perform what you need?

Comment: Also do you really need to keep older versions of your documents or would it be possible to move them to another index whenever a new version comes in? (since as stated in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730370/best-elasticsearch-alternative), indexing time is not important)

Comment: @Val thank you for your attention. It would be ok to create a secondary index. It would be also ok to move old versions to another index.  
One thing I forgot to mention: before aggregating the documents are filtered by time range, so we don't know which version is the latest at index time, only at search time.

Comment: Ok, but when indexing a new version of a document, would it be conceivable to first move the older version out of the "main" index into some kind of "history" index? The main idea here is to only keep the latest version of a document in the main index. That would de facto solve your case. Also what do you need the older versions for?

Comment: @Val Yes, it's possible to move older version out of the main index. But I don't see how this solve my issue :-(
I'm implementing possibility to specify date range, and see how documents looked like at this particular period of time, do searching, aggregation, and metrics on them. That's why I need to store all the versions and get latest ones for given period of time.

Comment: There's was no notion of date range in your initial question... Still, even if you specify a date range, there should only be one single version of each document within that date range, right? If you have a "main" index with all the latest versions, you already have a single version per document and your date range will apply on those.

Comment: @Val Imagine I have 2 documents created in 2014. They are in the "main" index. In 2015 I updated them, so I have 2 docs in "main" index, and 2 in "history" index. I'm applying date range, to see how documents looked like in 2014. Applying date range on "main" index gives me nothing, because all docs there are created  in 2015. So I need to apply date range to history index, and get the latest versions for each document. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124396/discussion-between-taras-kohut-and-val).

Comment: How frequently do you update your documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided samples and additional details in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124396/discussion-between-taras-kohut-and-val) I do not think you could achieve the required results using the aggregation. But I can propose an alternative solution instead:

1. Add property "***current***" of type *Boolean* which
   will be set to true for all the latest versions of the documents. If
   a new version is inserted - "***current***" will be set to *false*
   in an older version and set to true in a newer one.
2. Add property "***timepoints***" which will contain multiple values. In the end of the day (any other period can be used) for all the
   current records add the current timestamp (or any other id of the
   period, e.g. "09.30.2016", or "Jan") to the "***timepoints***"
   array.

**Pros**:

- You can easily retrieve the current records at some point of time just checking whether the time point is in the "***timepoints***" array.
- You can retrieve all the available time points from all the documents with a single query.
- You can do the aggregation by time points, e.g. to count all the records at every point of time.
- No need to maintain multiple indices, duplicates of the records etc., the algorithm is pretty straightforward.

**Cons**:

- No possibility to get the current versions at an arbitrary point of time, just the ones when the calculation was performed.
- The overall size of the "timepoints" arrays may increase significantly if you run the calculation too often and you have millions of records.

**Workarounds**:

- For more fine grained statistics run the calculation on an hourly basis. But once a day (or month, or year) remove some of the time points from the "***timepoints***" array for older periods of time. In the end you will have a set of time points that will correspond to every year (in case it was more than a year ago), every month (in case it was more than a month ago), every day (in case it was more than a day ago), and every hour for the latest period. Of course the algorithm of removal of time points can be improved according to you needs.
- If you are mostly working with the latest versions of the records - store them in a separate index, store the older versions in another one. In this case you don't even need the "current" property, just run through all the records in your current index and add the time stamp.

I can provide you all the queries you need for the above mentioned steps in case of a need.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at solving this client side. I can think of two ways to approach it.

1. Use the scroll api to go through all the documents and find the latest version of each. Then again client side, aggregate by `text`.
2. Use an elasticsearch terms aggregation on `doc_id` with a subaggregation of a [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) on `version`. This will give you the latest version for each document id. Then create a boolean OR terms filter that uses the doc_id and version from the first part. This filter should then have a terms aggregation on `text`.

Either way, you need to do some client side work. I don't believe scripting will help. If you already know the latest version number for each document, then this is a lot easier.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, each solution requires storing ids of all latest versions on the client side, before sending them to aggregation. It's impossible due to a huge amount of the data.

Comment: How many documents do you have?  Why do you need to keep the old versions of the docs? Or perhaps when you add a new version, you could move the old version to a different index. Another idea would be to have a flag on the newest version so you can filter by this `isNewest` field, but then you have to index the new version AND update the old version - making 2 reindex operations.

Comment: Please see our discussion with Val here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124396/discussion-between-taras-kohut-and-val